# React not re-rendering after integer state update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, state

I have a custom react hook that retrieves paginated data from the server and stores the data itself and the page number, number of pages, etc. I am trying to display the number of records returned, but for some reason, the page is not re-rendering even though the state has been updated. I know the state is updated because using that value as a dependency in a `useEffect` hook works fine and logs the changes to the console. It also shows the new value in the developer tools. Below is the code to the hook as well as the component the data is outputted to.

**hook**

```
import {Dispatch, SetStateAction, useContext, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {IPaginatedData} from '../interfaces/IPaginatedData';
import {apiCall} from '../apiCall';
import {AuthContext} from '../../state/AuthContext';

/**
 * Returns paginated data along with controls
 * @param {string} url
 * @param {string | null} queryParams
 * @return {array}
 */
export function usePaginatedData<T>(url: string, queryParams: string | null = null): [
  T[],
  [number, Dispatch<SetStateAction<number>>],
  [number, Dispatch<SetStateAction<number>>],
  [number, Dispatch<SetStateAction<number>>],
  () => void,
  number
] {
  const {token} = useContext(AuthContext);

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [totalPages, setTotalPages] = useState(0);
  const [countPerPage, setCountPerPage] = useState(20);
  const [data, setData] = useState<T[]>([]);
  // This is the record I want to display
  const [totalRecords, setTotalRecords] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    refresh();
  }, [page, countPerPage, token]);

  const refresh = () => {
    if (loading) {
      return;
    }

    setLoading(true);
    apiCall<IPaginatedData<T>>(
        `${url}${queryParams ? `?page=${page}&${queryParams}` : `?page=${page}`}`,
        'GET',
        'v1',
        null,
        {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
        }).then((result) => {
      if (!result) return;

      setTotalPages(result.pageCount);
      setData(result.data);
      setLoading(false);
      // I set it to the result from the server or 0 if the server returned null
      setTotalRecords(result.totalRecords ?? 0);
    }).catch((e) => {
      console.error(e);
      setLoading(false);
    });
  };

  return [
    data,
    [page, setPage],
    [totalPages, setTotalPages],
    [countPerPage, setCountPerPage],
    refresh,
    totalRecords,
  ];
}
```

**component**

```
const [products, [], [], [], refresh, totalProducts] = usePaginatedData<IPublicProduct>(
    'public/products', queryParams,
);

useEffect(() => refresh(), [queryParams]);

return (
  <>
    <SectionTitle type="h3">Total Products: {totalProducts}</SectionTitle>
    <ProductsList products={products} columns={columns}/>
  </>
);
```

I have not been able to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I really hope you already logged `result.totalRecords` in the hook and looked at its contents?

Comment: @James, this is in a hook. Once it happens, it returns the new values just fine within the component the hook is called in. I’ve got a useEffect call against  the returned value to verify that it does in fact do that.

Comment: @AndyRay yes I have. The values return just fine. I hooked up the return values to a useEffect call and it logs every time the value changes. So I know the component has access to the correct values.

Comment: Ok, then what does "the page is not re-rendering" mean? Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit this question (don't comment) with specifically what you expect to happen, and specifically what isn't happening.

Comment: @AndyRay I am sorry I don't quite understand. My question states that I expect to react to re-render after a state update however that is not happening. I do apologize this is my first time posting here so I may be doing a horrible job explaining things.

Comment: What does "not re-rendering" mean? Do you see "component"'s body execute when you put a console.log in it, meaning it's re-rendering? Do you not see `{totalProducts}` update? Which effect "works fine"? You have two hooks that call `refresh()`, is one running and one not when you debug with `conosle.log`? Where does it show the new value in the developer tools? The code you posted has no `console.log` in it.